# Upper semicontinuity in C(X)-algebras. Quotient norm question

Tags: c-star-algebras, norms, semicontinuity

[upper semicontinuity in C(X)-algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99860/upper-semicontinuity-in-cx-algebras)

In the 5th paragraph of this post, I don't understand why there exists a vector *b* satisfying $||a+b||_A < ||q_x (a)||_A(x)$

By the definition of the quotient norm, isn't $||q_x (a)||_{A(x)}$ the infimum?

I thought $||a+b||_A > ||q_x (a)||_A(x)$ for all $a \in A$

I think I'm definitely missing something here.

Thank you.